# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.mahout.driver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mahout, collaborative-filtering, mahout-recommender

#### I am trying to setup standalone Mahout on local machine where I can run spark-itemsimilarity command on it. I get following error :

```
$ ./mahout
Adding lib/ to CLASSPATH
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, running locally 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver
```

Similarly for spark-itemsimilarity

```
$ ./mahout spark-itemsimilarity
Adding lib/ to CLASSPATH
/Users/james/mahout/examples/target/classes:
...
...
:/Users/james/mahout/bin/mahout-spark-class.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver
```

#### This is what I have tried -

1. Downloaded Mahout 0.14, Spark and Hadoop
2. Built Mahout from source by using mvn -DskipTests -X clean install
3. tested it by mvn test
4. Environmental variable in bashrc_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
export MAHOUT_HOME=/Users/james/mahout
export MAHOUT_LOCAL=true
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/james/spark
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/james/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin



export PATH=$PATH$:MAHOUT_HOME/bin:$:MAHOUT_HOME/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

5. Started Spark master (standalone)